# Добавление элемента в инфоблок

Tags: php, битрикс

Пытаюсь добавить в инфоблок новый элемент, но на выходе получаю ошибку
такого рода "Для добавления элементов инфоблоков используйте вызов CIBlockElement::Add()"
Подскажите, что делаю не так.

```
use Bitrix\Main\Application; 
$request = Application::getInstance()->getContext()->getRequest(); 
$ib        = 31; 
$city      = $request->getPost("city"); 
$prop      = [];
$prop[464] = $city;


$result = \Bitrix\Iblock\ElementTable::add(
    [
        "MODIFIED_BY"    => $USER->GetID(),
        "IBLOCK_SECTION_ID" => false,
        "IBLOCK_ID"      => $ib,
        "PROPERTY_VALUES"=> $prop,
        "NAME"           => "Пользовательская статистика",
        "ACTIVE"         => "Y",
    ]
);

if($result->isSuccess())
{
    $ID = $result->getId();
    echo "Добавлен новый элемент: ".$ID;
}
else
{
    $error = $result->getErrorMessages();
    echo "Ошибка добавления нового элемента: <pre>".var_export($error, true)."</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Сравнительно не давно ведется перевод битрикс на новое ядро. Модуль инфоблоков очень важный и весьма обширный. Его еще не перевели в полном объеме. Поэтому эти методы (надеюсь, что пока) блокируются.

Answer (score 2):

Метод [Add()](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/add.php)

Посмотрите пример(самый первый). Достаточно понятно изложено.

Comment: фишка в том, что тот код который у меня в примере, написан с использованием ядра d7, поэтому мне и интересно в чём проблема

Comment: @ChromeChrome проблема в том, что этот модуль не переведен полностью на D7